# TypeError: 'int' object is not callable

Tags: python

```
def a_plus_abs_b(a, b):
"""Возвращает a+abs(b), но не использует abs.

>>> a_plus_abs_b(2, 3)
5
>>> a_plus_abs_b(2, -3)
5
"""
if b < 0:
    op = (0-b)+a
else:
    op = a+b
return op(a, b)
```

Код - проще некуда. Только сел за python и вот столкнулся с проблемой:  TypeError: 'int' object is not callable. Пересел с C#...наверно не разобрался с какой-то мелочью! Может подскажет кто и тыкнет носом в чём ошибка?

В задании написано исправить только строки, которые стоят в условии:

```
if b < 0:
    op = _____ 
else:
    op = _____
return op(a, b)
```

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Что должно происходить тут: op(a, b)?

Comment: На сколько я понимаю уже не посредственное сложение а и b в зависимости от знака b.

Comment: А что тогда происходит строчкой ранее? "op = a+b"

Comment: Сложение:) При условии, что b>0. Я нашёл курс  и там много заданий. Хочу их пройти. Задание: "Используя возможность присваивания существующим функциям новых имен, заполни пробелы в определении приведенной функции для сложения a с абсолютным значением b". Всё что до запятой мне не очень понятно, по крайней мере не могу провести аналогию с C#.

Comment: А зачем вам два сложения? Тем более, совершенно непонятно где в записи op(a, b) вы увидели сложение.

Comment: Я понял, что функция op и должна вернуть сумму. Она воткнута в a_plus_abs_b(a, b) для сложности как я понял. Ей передаются значения a и b и в op мы должны произвести расчёт. Разве нет?

Comment: А у вас op чем является, учитывая что "op = a+b"?

Comment: Это и смущает: в условии она переменная, а потом вызывается как функция.

Comment: Она - число, а не просто переменная. Вот тут-то у вас и ошибка - попытка "вызова" числа, о чем питон и говорит.

Comment: Очень странно, потому что в задании написано исправить только строки, которые стоя в условии. if b < 0:
        op = _____
    else:
        op = _____
    return op(a, b)

Comment: используйте лямбды `op = lambda a,b: (0-b) + a`

Comment: заработало, спасибо огромное!!!